# Is there a way to force preview to open files in the center of the screen

Tags: display, preview, screen, monterey

Whenever I open a pdf file with preview the window goes automatically to the most left side of the screen, is there a way to make it open files in the center? In case it's relevant I use an external monitor.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a direct solution but I use the Rectangle app (free) with a custom shortcut (opt-cmd-.) to center any active window, including Preview.